# create a vector for each column while keeping the first column

Tags: r

I would like to create a vector for each trait column (in the example below, columns a to t), wherein for each vector the first column and a trait column would be contained. The following is just a sample data frame. The actual data is larger.

```
string <- randomStrings(n=1000, len = 5, digits = T, upperalpha = T, 
                    loweralpha = T, unique = T, check = T)
df <- data.frame(replicate(21,sample(-100:150,80,rep = T)))
df[,1] <- string[1:80]
colnames(df)[-1] <- letters[1:20]
names(df)[1] <- paste("ID")
```

The desired script for the first three trait columns is shown below:

```
id_a <- df[,c(1,2)]
id_b <- df[,c(1,3)]
id_c <- df[,c(1,4)]
```

How should I do this for all trait columns in one run?

Comment: Do you mean `1:4` or `c(1, 4)`?

Comment: Right, it's [,c(1,4)]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will do it:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(df)) assign(paste0("id_", names(df)[i]), df[ , c(1, i)])
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting me re creation of subsets. Done with edits.

Comment: What if I want to know the `dim` in one run for all those vectors that were created?

Comment: I took out the part of my answer referring to your original column subsetting, since you fixed it.

Comment: The dimension of the resulting vectors will be the same as 1st dim of original data frame...so `nrow(df)`